# Why dec to string conversion not working correctly on android?

Tags: java, android, html-entities

I am making an android app which parses XML. Since XML data contains HTML hexes **(`&#<dec value>`)**, I need to convert them and then show them in my app. When I am passing **8217** to my code, it returns me some chinese/japanese (I'm not sure) character.
Here is my code.

```
public char decToChar(String dec){
    Int decimal = Integer.parseInt(dec, 16);
    return (char)decimal;
}
```

I am passing value '**8217**' to this method and it returns chinese character instead of **'**.

Do anyone have any idea why its not working?

Comment: why dont you simply use the unicode character notation, something like \u8217 if I am remembering it correctly?

Comment: \u8217 gives the same.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you expecting? You are probably correctly parsing the hex-value to 33303. But since you are casting it to (char) you generate a meaningless value. This is not a conversion to a character.

I would advice you to use apache commons if you can. [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) to unescape an [entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html):

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#8217;"));
```

Should show you the expected character `’`